# What can cause a SignalR connection to drop?

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a C# Windows Service running in approximately 500 locations. When the services start they initiate a connection with a remote SignalR hub running on a VM in AWS.  The connection/tunnel is then used for sending information from the server to each location throughout the day.

This has been running fine for the past 18 months, but for the past week the remote services have been losing connection and have to be restarted to reinitiate the connection with the server.  I'm using SignalR 2.4.1 which doesn't have the auto reconnection feature of the newer versions.

I've noticed that it seems to be happening about every 18 hours.  Nothing has changed on the clients or on the server that anyone is aware of.

I'm looking for ideas on what could be causing this.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not related to programming. Connections drop because of a number of situations, both physical and virtual. Issues/updates in network adapters, routers, VNETs, firewalls, OSes, VPNs, etc etc etc can cause a connection to drop.

Comment: I expected someone to make a comment about this not being programming related.  As a programmer reaching out for help with an issue that needs to be resolved, I would disagree.  Yes, connections drop because of the reasons you mentioned, but programmers need to know what those issues are so they can respond appropriately.  SignalR rides on the back of those items you listed, so to say "this is not related to programming" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Well, an insane number of technologies run on those, some related to programming and some not. This issue is entirely unrelated to SignalR (which itself only connects to the server with a single, probably WebSockets, connection). Without a reconnection feature, all you can do is implement reconnection yourself. Now, if you asked how to implement reconnection, that's another story. This as it is, is too broad for StackOverflow, and the issue could lie miles away from your code (and servers for that matter)

Comment: Do you also experience disconnects from eg your dev env connected to the same AWS?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm unable to connect to the prod environment from my dev environment, but considering the other locations are geographically spread out, I would expect the same result.  If I were to try this, what might it tell me if it does or does not lose connection?

Comment: Is it all services or just a few? Different or same? Are connection losses simultaneous or spread? Does it look like a timeout (all clients disconnect about 18h after they connect) or sporadic (any client may disconnect any time after it connects)

Comment: As for detecting a loss of connectivity, I don't know what you have coded or how you're detecting it already - pings/heartbeats stopping?

Comment: The way TCP/IP works, unless the local network goes down (as in, you pull out the cable or disable the network card), the machine itself will be unable to divine any detail about why a connection is dropped, only that it has dropped, so the reason is typically quite irrelevant from the software end. SignalR is not special there. You'll need to implement some sort of retry or reconnect; if you can't, consult your nearest network engineer for troubleshooting. "I'm looking for ideas" is simply not a question suitable for SO, as it is completely open-ended and doesn't admit a "correct" answer.

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm doing a heartbeat detection.  And when one dies they all start dying.  At first I thought it was sporadic, but it does seem to be fairly regular at about 18 hours.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for your input.  And yes, I agree that the question is open-ended and may not be the best for SO.  Thanks for providing input anyway.

Comment: So then I guess you need to see whether it's a server end failure or an "each client reaching some limit" - how about you get them all running then restart half after 3h.. do those restarted last 3h longer than the others before they start failing or do they fail at the same time

Comment: Do two things:  run a Wireshark trace on one of the clients and run a SignalR trace on the server.  Also, please look/trace the resource use on the server.  Do they stay constant of do they do up?  For the server, do you use a backplane?

Comment: Also, are any of your clients Chrome or Chromium based?  There is a "bug" in SignalR that causes Chrome connections to die.  You need to update to version 2.4.2 to "fix" it.